# Jquery fadeIn and CSS media queries

Tags: jquery, css

**The problem:**

I've got a nav bar that fades in on page load. Then a block of text fades in on a delay. Due to the fact fading in causing inline styles on the text element, this then breaks the media query that is set to hide the text at a smaller screen resolution.

If you remove the script doing the fade for the text, you will see what I mean. How can I get around this problem so that the jQuery doesn't break my media query. So, how could i get the text to fade in only when the media query has the element visible?

**jsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/visualdecree/RAWUG/

**CSS**

```
.banner-title{
    display: none;
}

.bar-top{
    height: auto;
    padding: 1.3em 0 1.3em 0;
    background: pink;
    margin: -135px 0 2.5em 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
    .banner-title{
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        color: #333;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        padding: 0 0 0 1%;
    }
}​
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

    $(".bar-top").delay(700).animate({marginTop:'0px'}, 750, 'swing');

    $(".banner-title").delay(1500).addClass("fade");
        $(".fade").fadeIn("slow")
        $(".fade").css("display":"none");
        $(".fade").hide();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it would appear my solution is holding up ok. Anyone with an improvement please feel free to add to this. I found the fix to be running a second function that basically looks at the screen width and overides any inline styles set by the `fadeIn` that runs on page load.

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/visualdecree/RAWUG/4/

If you see a problem or error please let me know, this might help someone with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error `$(".fade").css("display":"none");` should be `$(".fade").css("display", "none");` or `$(".fade").css({"display":"none"});`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the positioning of the links they get moved down relative to the text that fades in , I fixed it [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RAWUG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one, self-explanatory,  way to do it: (fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/RAWUG/3/ )

```
    $(".bar-top").delay(700).animate({
        marginTop: '0px'
    }, 750, 'swing');


    if ( $(".banner-title").css('display') == 'block' ) {
        $(".banner-title").delay(1500).addClass("fade");
        $(".fade").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".fade").hide();
    }
```

Comment: Looking at the fiddle i can see it's adding the class ok, but i can't see anything different happening? It's not hiding the element

Comment: Yes. Ok, this does work if you start out with the screen already below the breaking point you set on your media query (usually what will happen). It doesn't work if the animation happens and then, afterwards, you shrink the window's width. I'll post a solution with it working that way too.

Comment: Thanks, i been trying to work it out for ages. I look forward to seeing the solution!

Comment: Not sure this is a particularly elegant solution, but i've got this, which appears to be doing the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/visualdecree/RAWUG/4/